# OpenCart : Send order confirmation email to multiple email addresses

Tags: php, opencart

I have configured OpenCart store and I want the copy of Order Confirmation email on my 2 email accounts. I have tried `vQmode` but it is not working. I have tried every possible methods but I got nothing. please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your admin panel, goto System Tab-> Setting.

Click on Edit and goto Mail Tab.

The Last option, has additional Mail Alerts where you can specify additional mail ids with separated by comma